# MVC Jquery go to controller action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In Jquery, I need to tell the program to go to EmployeeController and Empl action. How do I tell it do this. I want to simple way to do this without using ajax.

Comment: What do you mean? You want to navigate to a new page?

Comment: "Go to"?  Have what go to?  The entire page?  An AJAX call?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
window.location.href = "/{controller}/{action}" //in your case, /employee/empl
```

This works because of the routes specified in your Global.asax.cs file.  I suggest you read up on how this works as it's one of the fundamentals of MVC....

Comment: better use location.href = 'whatever';

Comment: @BigMike Added ".href" to the end.  Thanks for the feedback, you're probably right that it's perhaps clearer as window.location is an object.

Comment: and if I want to pass a parameter ?

Comment: if someone wanted to pass a parameter, one would just do window.location.href = "/{controller}/{action}?{parameter}={value}&{parameter2}={value}

Answer (score 5):

Well, all good response so far, but using a magic string for building url just gives me the chills. I prefer to add an extension like this:

```
public static string GetUrl(this HtmlHelper, helper, string Action, string Controller, object RouteValues)
{
    UrlHelper Url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
    return Url.Action(Action, Controller, RouteValues);
}
```

and then in my js code use:

```
location.href = '@Html.GetUrl("Action", "Controller", new { foo=Model.Foo })';
```

It's more consistent, internally cares about routing, and gives me a centralized point where doing nasty things on Urls :)

Well, one more thing,

```
window.location = "whatever";
```

is good and works, still

```
location.href = "whatever";
```

is preferreable.

HTH

Comment: There already _is_ a helper for that: `@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { foo = Model.bar })`

Comment: @KristofClaes: yes there'is, of course, and as you can see it's used internally, the own helper is just to have a centralized way in which I can do nasty things on urls, ideally there's no need of that in ideal world, but sometimes the requirements are so funny that I had to resort to this. Of course I've removed my logic in the sample code, posting a mock of my real helper :)

Comment: Another downside... What happens when this script doing the relocating isn't in a view (as it shouldn't be)?  You can't use your helper methods. Instead it should be perfectly clear to just redirect to a route.

Comment: @AdamTerlson: not really a downside, I usually pass urls (and model props) inside js object's properties (I'm a purist of having js code in js files). In that case I cannot see a way to use MS Action helper either. Until Razor Engine will be able to apply it's magic in js files I guess we should live with this "downside". The important point of my solution is keeping url generation generic (using RouteData structures) e.g. not implying that a certain route exists and have the MVC engine resolve them.

Comment: Right, I wasn't arguing *for* Action or your method, I was saying that none of them will work and he'll just have to code the URL manually as I suggested in my answer.  Sometimes you just need to assume that navigation will work.

Comment: Sorry I don't see your point (and probably this is due to my very bad English). If I need an url in a js file, I simply write a function/object and I set it in the view (via document.ready() or directly on js call. Forgive me bu I cannot see any scenarios when a flow is not passing at least one time from a view/controller, can you give me a sample of what you mean exactly ?

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer doesn't work when the application is Published.
I had to use

```
window.location.href='@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")'
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Making assumptions about the URI structure & routing, but:

`window.location = '/employee/empl/';`

Comment: Only if he has his route set up to be `/controller/action`

Comment: Yea. Added a "disclaimer" moments ago.

Answer (score 0):

and for parameters

```
window.location.href = "/{controller}/{action}?parm1=val1&parm2=val2"
```